# Hibernate 4, JPA 2 and HSQL, not able to query by ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hsqldb

I have a domain object called Service that contains an id field amongst others:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "type")
private Service.ServiceTypes serviceType;
```

In my DAO implementation, I can easily query by serviceType:

```
@Override
    public Set<Service> queryDatabaseByServiceType(ServiceTypes serviceType) {
        logger.debug("Querying the database by service type " + serviceType.toString());
        return new HashSet<Service>(super.entityManager.createQuery("from Service s where s.type = :serviceType").setParameter("serviceType", serviceType).getResultList());
    }
```

When I copy and past that method and try to run the query against "id", I get zero results.

```
@Override
    public Service queryDatabaseByServiceId(int id) {
List<Service> results = super.entityManager.createQuery("from Service s where s.id = :id").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
return results.get(0);
```

always returns nothing....  I've tried it a million different ways...

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = super.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Service> criteria = builder.createQuery(Service.class);
Root<Service> s1 = criteria.from(Service.class);
TypedQuery<Service> query = super.entityManager.createQuery(
    criteria.select(s1).where(builder.equal(s1.get("id"), id)));
Service service = query.getSingleResult();
return service;
```

Still nothing.  I'm not sure why I can query against other columns but not the ID.  I've verified the IDs I'm passing in are valid, nothing ever works.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  Here are other ways I've tried the query:

```
Service ser = super.entityManager.find(Service.class, new Integer(1));

List z1 = super.entityManager.createQuery("select s.id from Service s").getResultList();

List results1 = super.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Service s WHERE id = 1").getResultList();

List<Service> results = super.entityManager.createQuery("from Service as s where s.id = :id").setParameter("id", new Integer(1)).getResultList();
```

I've tried changing the field in my domain object to "idx" instead of "id", I've tried changing the column name to "service_id" thinking maybe there's some internal conflict between what it uses for the id field and my object, but still nothing.  As noted before and in the comments, querying by any other field works fine and I can easily get results showing the IDs:

```
return new HashSet<Service>(super.entityManager.createQuery("from Service s where s.type = :serviceType").setParameter("serviceType", serviceType).getResultList());
```

produces a populated list and when converted to json i see this in my browser:

```
{"services":[{"id":2,"serviceType":"x",.....
```

With all those various types of queries, here is the log output:

```
DEBUG: service.impl.ServiceServiceImpl - Querying the database by service id 2
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as service1_0_, service0_.description as descript2_0_, service0_.name as name0_, service0_.type as type0_, service0_.tmodel as tmodel0_, service0_.uddi_id as uddi6_0_, service0_.url as url0_, service0_.version as version0_ from services service0_ where service0_.service_id=?
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 1
INFO : service.impl.ServiceServiceImpl - results list from id query: 0
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as service1_0_0_, service0_.description as descript2_0_0_, service0_.name as name0_0_, service0_.type as type0_0_, service0_.tmodel as tmodel0_0_, service0_.uddi_id as uddi6_0_0_, service0_.url as url0_0_, service0_.version as version0_0_ from services service0_ where service0_.service_id=?
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 1
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as col_0_0_ from services service0_
INFO : service.impl.ServiceServiceImpl - z1 count: 0
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as service1_0_, service0_.description as descript2_0_, service0_.name as name0_, service0_.type as type0_, service0_.tmodel as tmodel0_, service0_.uddi_id as uddi6_0_, service0_.url as url0_, service0_.version as version0_ from services service0_ where service0_.service_id=1
INFO : service.impl.ServiceServiceImpl - results1 from id query: 0
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as service1_0_, service0_.description as descript2_0_, service0_.name as name0_, service0_.type as type0_, service0_.tmodel as tmodel0_, service0_.uddi_id as uddi6_0_, service0_.url as url0_, service0_.version as version0_ from services service0_ where service0_.service_id=2
INFO : service.impl.ServiceServiceImpl - results2 from id query: 0
Hibernate: select service0_.service_id as service1_0_0_, service0_.description as descript2_0_0_, service0_.name as name0_0_, service0_.type as type0_0_, service0_.tmodel as tmodel0_0_, service0_.uddi_id as uddi6_0_0_, service0_.url as url0_0_, service0_.version as version0_0_ from services service0_ where service0_.service_id=?
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 2
```

Comment: No idea, but why don't you simply use `Service s = em.find(Service.class, id);`?

Comment: I did try that -- also no results... it's like it's storing the ID differently than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use JPA2 in our project, but it doesn't have this kind of problem, How about change the "public Service queryDatabaseByServiceId(int id) {"  id type to Integer, in my opinion, in hibernate Integer will be a better choice. Let me know what happen. Another thing is that change log4j to print the sql as well as the parameter value to check it.

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <level value="trace"></level>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.sql">
    <level value="trace"></level>
</logger>
```

Comment: I've already tried using Integer and still nothing.  I changed the table name of id to service_id just to see if there were some weird comment.  Here is the creation line from hibernate: Hibernate: create table services (service_id integer not null, description varchar(255), name varchar(255), type integer, tmodel varchar(255), uddi_id varchar(255), url varchar(255), version varchar(255), primary key (service_id))

Comment: can i write the database to a file instead of in memory so i can directly see the table/columns/values?

Comment: No.acturaly It's just about log4j, you add the code that I pasted then can see the parameter value.

Comment: When I run the query I can see this in the log:  TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 2, however it still returns zero results. When I query by service type, it returns results:  {"services":[{"id":2,"serviceType": "x".......

Comment: Well, turns out I made a big goof -- I'm storing the results in a map in memory as well as in the db.  The queries that I thought were working were actually using the map, not querying the database.  Turns out, all queries return 0 items, including "findAll()".  I opened a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111077/unable-to-get-any-results-from-hibernate-4-jpa-2-hsql-query

Comment: scratch that... here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112833/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-1-context-visibility